B2C Custom Policy REST API error - Bad Request
I have a B2c Custom policy defined that is supposed to call a token endpoint. Here is how I have tried to configure the policy:
<TechnicalProfile Id="GetTokenInformation">
  <DisplayName>Get Token Information</DisplayName>
  <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
  <Metadata>
    <Item Key="ServiceUrl">https://myazb2cidporg.b2clogin.com/myazb2cidporg.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/token</Item>
    <Item Key="AuthenticationType">None</Item>
    <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">Body</Item>
    <Item Key="HttpBinding">POST</Item>
  </Metadata>
  <CryptographicKeys>
    <Key Id="client_secret_post" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_myfederatedwebappsecret" />
  </CryptographicKeys>
  <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="code" PartnerClaimType="code" Required="true" />
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="redirect_uri" DefaultValue="https://jwt.ms" />
  </InputClaims>
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="accessToken" PartnerClaimType="access_token" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="refreshToken" PartnerClaimType="refresh_token" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="idToken" PartnerClaimType="id_token" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" PartnerClaimType="given_name" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" PartnerClaimType="family_name" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" PartnerClaimType="name" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="email" />
  </OutputClaims>
  <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
</TechnicalProfile>

When tested the policy gives an error specifically for the Rest API call:

Exception Message:The claims exchange 'GetTokenInformation' specified in step '7' returned HTTP error response with Code 'BadRequest' and Reason 'Bad Request'., Exception Type:InvalidResponseException, CorrelationID:8bfd390f-62fa-4250-b0f5-4aa9d27c901f.

Additional details from traces:
"Key": "Exception",
Copy
    "Value": {
      "Kind": "Handled",
      "HResult": "80131500",
      "Message": "The claims exchange 'GetTokenInformation' specified in step '7' returned HTTP error response with Code 'BadRequest' and Reason 'Bad Request'.",
      "Data": {
        "IsPolicySpecificError": false
      },
      "Exception": {
        "Kind": "Handled",
        "HResult": "80131500",
        "Message": "Processing of the HTTP request resulted in an exception. Please see the HTTP response returned by the 'Response' property of this exception for details.",
        "Data": {}
      }

Unsure why this error is cropping up. How to address this issue?
